# TabLayout title not showing properly

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I've created a SlidingTabs with only 2 tabs however the layout is not properly being shown. `Image 1` is the output that I always get and `Image 2` is the output I'm expect to achieve

Output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pager_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <test.com.example.view.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try   `tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `TabLayout` available in design support library

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/my_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabPaddingBottom="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabPaddingTop="-1dp" />
```

In your app gradle file, add below line in dependencies:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Java code will be as below:

```
TabLayout myTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_tab_layout);
TabLayout.Tab tab1 = myTabLayout.newTab().setText("Details");
TabLayout.Tab tab2 = myTabLayout.newTab().setText("Cast");
myTabLayout.addTab(tab1);
myTabLayout.addTab(tab2);
```

I hope this will help you.